# Нужно сделать шаблонную функцию с поведением std::count

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, count, std

есть задание написать шаблонную функцию, которая будет вести себя как std::count.
Я читал пример реализации в документации, но это не совсем то, нужно что-то попроще.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void cot(T t, T t1, U u){
    int counter = 0;
    std::vector<U>arr;
    for (; t !=t1 ; ++t) {
       if(u == t){
           counter++;
       }

    }

}
```

Получилось что-то такое, но в if выдает ошибку. T в шаблоне должен принимать два итератора(на конце и начало), а U это искомое значение.

Answer (score 3):

Да куда проще-то, чем приведенный [пример реализации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    count(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Ну плюньте на возвращаемый тип, сделав его просто `int`... Вот, в ваших обозначениях:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
int count(InputIt t, InputIt t1, const T& u)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (; t != t1; ++t) {
        if (*t == u) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

P.S. Если не секрет - а зачем вы воткнули в свою функцию вектор?...

Comment: *t == u. Ошибку выдает в этом месте

Comment: Для **каких** типов? Естественно, что тип, на который указывает итератор, должен быть сравним с типом значения... Например, бессмысленно передавать итераторы на вектор int'ов, а значение - строку... Конечно, можно поизвращаться и записать условие, что это должны быть сравниваемые типы, но вы же сами попросили - попроще :)